# Word JavaScript API to modify Document.Styles or Document.ListTemplates collection

Tags: javascript, vba, office-js

I would like to access and modify Document.Styles or Document.ListTemplates using Word JavaScript API.

For example , in Word VBA we can modify the font size of the style as

ActiveDocument.Styles(“Heading1”).Font.Size= 10

I would like to do the same thing through JavaScript API. Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add custom styles, you'll need to insert them as OOXML. You can insert OOXML into the document using the [body.insertOoxml()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body#insertooxmlooxml-string-insertlocation-insertlocation) function. Once your style is defined in the document, you can apply it to a [paragraph](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/paragraph) or [range](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/range) object.

Unfortunately, the simplified syntax you are used to from VBA isn't supported by Office.js at the moment. I would suggest adding this to the [Office UserVoice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) for consideration.